# pandas selecting original format of to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I have the following df:

```
df

index          Original Date                          
19.02.2021     19.02.2021  
19.02.2021     19.02.2021  
...                 
04.12.2020     04.12.2020 
03.12.2020     03.12.2020
```

I would like to set index column as an index, however it is at the moment string type object so, I convert it to datetime object and then set as an index.

```
df['index'] = pd.date_time(df['index'])
df = df.set_index('index')
```

It looks like this:

```
df

             Original Date
index          
2021-02-19   19.02.2021
2021-02-19   19.02.2021
2021-02-18   18.02.2021
2021-02-18   18.02.2021
2021-02-17   17.02.2021
...
2020-04-12   04.12.2020
2020-03-12   03.12.2020
```

As you can see pandas can succesfully convert some of the dates. However some days like `04.12.2020` is converted to `12.04.2020`. So how can I specify the original format is `'dd.mm.yyyy'`, so that pandas can convert this string object to datetime successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the format as a parameter

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: @oakca what about this one

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime' , as you also said I think it will convert it to string, but I dont really wanna convert it to string

Comment: format = '%d.%m.%Y' just this works though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: ValueError: time data 19.02.2021 doesn't match format specified

Comment: This will change the index to string datatype. He wants it in datetime